# Link list of Google Forms to list Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a template google form that I need to create a copy of and link to a specific sheet. I need to repeat this process well over 200 times since we have 200 of the specific sheet.

If I make the copy of the form, and use a column (Col A) of the 200 forms and then the 200 specific sheets on another column (Col B) is there a way to make a script to link the forms in Col A to the respective sheet in Col B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this sample Google Spreadsheet [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) below, which is based from a sample at [FormApp DestinationType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type) article:

> The script below creates copies of the Google Form template file (they'll be saved to your Google Drive via a Folder named "FormTemplateCopies") and each copies will be linked to the Spreadsheet files added on your sheet (the spreadsheet URLs on Column B).

***Sample Script***

```
function linkToForms() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  //URLs of the sheet files are in Column B
  var urls = ss.getRange("B2:B"+ss.getDataRange().getLastRow()).getValues(); 
  //File ID of the Form template file is on A2
  var templateFileID = ss.getRange("A2").getValue(); 

  urls.forEach(url => {
      var form = FormApp.openById(formCopyID(templateFileID));
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      // Update the form's response destination.
      form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
      Logger.log("Done linking a copy of Form template file to sheet file \""+ss.getName()+"\"");
  });
}

function formCopyID(templateFileID) {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("FormTemplateCopies");
  if(destFolder.hasNext() == false){
    //Create a folder to contain the copies of the Form template file
    DriveApp.createFolder("FormTemplateCopies"); 
    linkToForms();
  }else{
    var dstFolderId = destFolder.next().getId();
    //Put the file ID of the original Form template file
    var fileToCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileID);
    //Creates a copy of the Form template file and place it into the FormTemplateCopies folder in your Google Drive
    var newCopyfile = fileToCopy.makeCopy(DriveApp.getFolderById(dstFolderId));
    //Gets the file ID of the new copy of the Form template file
    return newCopyfile.getId();
  }
}
```

**Sample Results:**

> Sample sheet file with data (Form template file ID was added on cell `A2` & 2 sample Spreadsheet file URLs were added on cell `B2` and below)

[image]

> After running the function `linkToForms()` on the Apps Script editor, here's the result

[image]

***A copy of the Form template now linked to Sheet 1:***

[image]

***Another copy of the Form template now linked to Sheet 2:***

[image]